# How do we prove that the image of a basis is also a basis of a transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space and $T:V\rightarrow V$ be an convertible linear operator. IF $B =\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n \}$ is a basis of $V$, show that $B' =\{TX_1,TX_2,...,TX_n\}$ is also a basis of $V.$

Answer (score 0):

As the dimension of $V$ is $n$, it suffices to show that $\left\{T(x_1),T(x_2), \dots ,T(x_n)\right\}$ is linearly independent (or generating).

Let's prove that it is linearly independent: Assume 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iT(x_i)=0.$$
We can rewrite the left-hand side as $T(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ix_i)$ since $T$ is linear. Since $T$ is injective (indeed, $T$ is invertible and thus bijective), $\ker(T)=\left\{0\right\}$. It follows that $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ix_i=0$. Since $\left\{x_1,x_2, \dots,x_n\right\}$ is a basis of $V$, we have that $\lambda_i=0$ for each $i$. This shows linear independence.

As an exercise, try to show that $\left\{T(x_1),T(x_2), \dots ,T(x_n)\right\}$ is generating as well. You will need to use that $T$ is surjective at some point.

Comment: Suppose I say that  since B' is of dimension R^n, then its a basis as well, does it make sense? Thanks